# Repeated kernel panic: anyone able to decipher report?

Tags: kernel-panic

I am getting repeated kernel panics. I have run many disk repair routines using Disk Utility and Techtool (6) but still happening. It seems to happen when I am using a particular application (Sonuus i2M Editor) which is a USB Pitch to MIDI converter.

The kernel panics are hard to know what if anything will help narrow this down...

```
Interval Since Last Panic Report: 242584 sec
Panics Since Last Report: 12
Anonymous UUID: FA99C24C-CBDE-48BB-A21B-2C3120FE05E9

Fri Jun 22 20:00:59 2012
panic(cpu 0 caller 0x235410): "zalloc: \"ipc kmsgs\" (3240864 elements) retry fail 3, kfree_nop_count: 0"@/SourceCache/xnu/xnu-1504.15.3/osfmk/kern/zalloc.c:992
Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address (4 potential args on stack)
0x4c1927d8 : 0x21b837 (0x5dd7fc 0x4c19280c 0x223ce1 0x0) 
0x4c192828 : 0x235410 (0x594ac8 0x592060 0x3173a0 0x3)
```

Comment: I'd say the problem is that your app/hardware is crashing the OS. You should contact the vendor's support. I'm not especially skilled at deciphering crash reports; maybe someone else will be able to provide more info.

Comment: For your next Console dump try to remove your computer name. Replace "paulkimmel" with "username" or something. Of course only if you care about your privacy. Furthermore the thread named in the kernel panic is related to the i2M musicport device. According to their website their device is compatible with the Mac, so it should work ok. Did you update all the drivers/firmware?

Comment: Looks like a driver is causing the problem....did you install anything recently?

Answer (score 3):

After contacting Sonuus, the software vendor has confirmed problem is with the app and is currently working on a bug fix.

Comment: Just wait a bit and you can select the answered check mark to let everyone know this is solved. It's over to the left of this comment...   <------ (there) and looks like [this](http://cl.ly/HbN3)